# Location manager icon still displayed even when I call stopUpdatingLocation

Tags: ios, ios6, core-location, cllocationmanager

Even though I called `stopUpdatingLocation` on my location manager, the location manager icon is still on the top right of my iPhone. Why hasn't it stopped?

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why the location arrow on your phone may still be on even after calling `stopUpdatingLocation`.

For one, another app on your phone may currently be using your location.

Another possibility is that you enabled significant location change monitoring using the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` method but forgot to turn this off using the `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` method. Apps that are monitoring significant location changes will display a solid arrow in the status bar in the same way apps that are using standard location updates do.

Of course it's also possible that you are for whatever reason incorrectly calling `stopUpdatingLocation` and you actually are still getting location updates from a location manager. To check if this is happening wait several minutes after calling `stopUpdatingLocation` and go to Settings>Privacy>Location Services and find your app. If there is a solid purple arrow next to your app then your app is indeed currently using location services and something most likely went wrong when calling `stopUpdatingLocation`. However if there is a solid gray arrow, this just signifies that your app has recently used location services and it's likely that you did correctly stop getting updates. Another way to check if you correctly turned off location updates is by calling your `CLLocationManager`'s `location` property and checking its `timestamp` property to make sure that it is not recent. If the timestamp is greater than the timestamp at which you called `stopUpdatingLocation` then you know something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The icon you see at the top is not locationManager, is the location service of the device. If you deactivate in settings no longer appears.